# AudioPlayer' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)

Tags: c#

I tried to audio messenger in cross platform and I found one plugin.AudioRecorder but I need xaml and cs functional.

```
 Error CS1061: 'AudioPlayer' does not contain a definition for
 'FinishedPlaying' and no extension method 'FinishedPlaying' accepting
 a first argument of type 'AudioPlayer' could be found (are you missing
 a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Qbakbak.iOS)
```

please any one help me..

Answer (score 0):

1) Ensure that your references are correct and up to date(You might not be referencing the plugin .dll in your project)

2) Check your using statements (using AudioRecorder;)

3) Make sure you are in the correct namespace

4) Clean / Rebuild your project

Comment: actually  I trying to audio msg like hike,whatsapp...   please can you help me